# How to fix 'unable to dequeue a cell' error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having some difficulty and haven't been able to find any solutions within other SO answers...

I have two tableviews within one viewcontroller, and they both work fine switching back and forth, but only if one of them is loaded first.

When I try to load the other one first (which I'll want to do sometimes depending on the user's path to the table), the app crashes with the error "unable to dequeue a cell with identifier customMessageCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard"

I've registered the nib for both custom cells in the viewDidLoad, identified the prototype cells in the storyboard, etc. Basically, all the usual solutions when I searched this error

Within my viewDidLoad:

```
messageTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomMessageCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customMessageCell")
listTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ItemCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "itemCell")
```

Also, I have an enum that switches the tables

```
switch currentTable {
case .list:
   tableSelected(table: "list")
case .notes:
   tableSelected(table: "notes")
```

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        switch currentTable {
        case .list:
            let cell = tableView.createCell(tableView: listTableView, indexPath: indexPath, itemArray: listArray)
            return cell
        case .notes:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customMessageCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomMessageCell

            if messageArray.count == 0 {
                cell.messageBody.text = "No notes yet"
            } else {
                cell.messageBody.text = messageArray[indexPath.row].messageBody
                cell.senderUser.text = messageArray[indexPath.row].sender

                let user = cell.senderUser.text

                switch user {
                case "jeffrey@sandiegomentors.com":
                    cell.avatarImageView.image = UIImage(named: "team-4")
                case "djones219@pointloma.edu":
                    cell.avatarImageView.image = UIImage(named: "team-3")
                case "dave@sandiegomentors.com":
                    cell.avatarImageView.image = UIImage(named: "team-2")
                case "amirthought@gmail.com":
                    cell.avatarImageView.image = UIImage(named: "team-6")
                case "james@sandiegomentors.com":
                    cell.avatarImageView.image = UIImage(named: "team-1")
                default:
                    cell.avatarImageView.image = UIImage(named: "twitteregg")
                }

                if cell.senderUser.text == Auth.auth().currentUser?.email as String? {
                    cell.messageBackground.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.005996327382, green: 0.4056355059, blue: 0.8481400013, alpha: 1)
                } else {
                    cell.messageBackground.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3254587054, green: 0.325510323, blue: 0.3254474401, alpha: 1)
                }

                if let timeStamp = messageArray[indexPath.row].time {
                    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeStamp/1000)
                    let formatter = DateFormatter()
                    formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy"
                    let dateString = formatter.string(from: date)
                    cell.timeLabel.text = dateString
                }
            }

            return cell
        }
```

```
func tableSelected(table: String) {
        if table == "list" {
            listTableView.isHidden = false
            messageTableView.isHidden = true
            messageInputView.isHidden = true
            addButton.isEnabled = true

            currentTable = .list

            buttonSelection(selected: tabButtons[1], unselected: tabButtons[0])

            buttonTodoWidthConstraint.isActive = true
            buttonNotesWidthConstraint.isActive = false

            listTableView.reloadData()

        } else {

            messageTableView.isHidden = false
            messageInputView.isHidden = false
            listTableView.isHidden = true
            addButton.isEnabled = false

            currentTable = .notes

            buttonSelection(selected: tabButtons[0], unselected: tabButtons[1])

            buttonNotesWidthConstraint.isActive = true
            buttonTodoWidthConstraint.isActive = false

            messageTableView.reloadData()
            scrollToBottom()
        }
    }
```

When I run the app and have the initial currentTable as .list, I can switch between the two (by a button that switches the enum value), and it works as expected.

When I have the initial currentTable as .notes, it crashes immediately.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's most likely something in your tableSelected method. Maybe you're calling it too soon? Is it possible for you to post that method?

Comment: Added those methods to the question

Comment: Unrelated, but I’d discourage instantiating a date formatter inside `cellFor`. It’s a notoriously expensive process. Better to instantiate it once, save it in some property, and reference this formatter from `cellFor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting an “unable to dequeue a cell” error even though each table has registered its appropriate cell identifier, that means that you likely instantiated a cell for one table when `cellFor` was called for the other. This is easy to do when you have a single set of `UITableViewDataSource` methods servicing both tables. You can confirm this by adding a breakpoint in `cellFor`, compare the `tableView` passed to that method to your two outlets for `messageTableView` and `listTableView`: Ensure sure you’re instantiating a cell appropriate for that table.

Rather than having `cellFor` rely upon `currentTable`, I’d suggest just checking `tableView` to determine which type of cell is to be instantiated. Then it’s impossible to instantiate the wrong cell at all. You can probably even eliminate `currentTable` altogether.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch tableView {
    case messageTableView:
        ...

    case listTableView:
        ...

    default:
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

---

Frankly, I’d discourage using a single `UITableViewDataSource` for two different tables. An alternative is to encapsulate the `UITableViewDataSource` for each into its own object, and it again makes it impossible to instantiate the wrong cell for the given table. It also helps mitigate view controller bloat.

Comment: Thank you Rob, appreciate the guidance. Will look into having two data sources, and your tips about how to format the `cellFor` has already paid off. Also thanks for the tip about the date formatter!